# Google map default tiptool slanted arrow styling

Tags: google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style google map default tooltip with slanted arrow. Would like dynamic to expand with the content.
How would I write the style to slant the arrow.

Like this
http://cdn.instantshift.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/free-map-navigation-psd-09.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default info window is not styleable in that fashion. You would need to use a [3rd party library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) to accomplish this (or write your own).